# ComponentResolver injection error

Tags: angular

I am trying to inject ComponentResolver in my component. I am using Angular 2 version 2.0.0-rc.1. My component definition is as follows.

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, Input, ComponentRef,  ComponentResolver, ComponentFactory, OnChanges, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: "wizardtab-content-container",
template: `<div #target>Hi</div>`
})

export class WizardTabContentContainer  {

@ViewChild('target', { read: ViewContainerRef }) target; 
@Input() type;
compRef: ComponentRef<any>;
private isViewInitialized: boolean = false;

constructor(private compResolver: ComponentResolver) {
    console.log("Constructor called");
}
}
```

When I add it to my application I am getting following error.

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Unable to get property
>   'query' of undefined or null reference    at resolvePromise
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:538:26)    at
>   Anonymous function
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:574:18)    at
>   ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:354:18)    at
>   onInvokeTask (eval code:36:25)    at ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:354:18)    at
>   Zone.prototype.runTask
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:22)    at
>   drainMicroTaskQueue
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:474:26)    at
>   invoke
>   (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:426:22)

If I comment constructor in this component which has ComponentResolver parameter then there is no error and div tag with "Hi" is rendered. Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: In the import statement, are you sure you have `ComponentResolver` instead of `componentResolver`?

Comment: @pythonista: In actual code its ComponentResolver. I made mistake while copy pasting code. Updated question.